# Why are the buttons inside the UIView squashed to the top?

Tags: swift, uiview, slider, range, avfoundation

I have installed the `ABVideoRangeSlider` pod into my project,
it all works fine besides that the start, end and progress sliders are squashed to the top.
Here's my code:

```swift
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import Photos
import AVKit
import ABVideoRangeSlider

class SliderTest: UIViewController, ABVideoRangeSliderDelegate {

    var url: URL?
    var rangeSlider: ABVideoRangeSlider!

    let rangeView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
        view.backgroundColor = .lightText

        self.rangeSlider = ABVideoRangeSlider()
        rangeView.addSubview(rangeSlider)

        self.view.addSubview(rangeView)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(rangeView)
        rangeView.bringSubviewToFront(rangeSlider)
        rangeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.rangeView.anchor(top: nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor,
                              right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 20, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 40)
        self.rangeSlider.delegate = self
        rangeSlider.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        rangeSlider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: rangeView.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        rangeSlider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: rangeView.centerYAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        rangeSlider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        rangeSlider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        rangeSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        rangeSlider.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        rangeSlider.clipsToBounds = false
        rangeSlider.autoresizesSubviews = true
        rangeSlider.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
        rangeSlider.isOpaque = true
        rangeSlider.semanticContentAttribute = .unspecified
        rangeSlider.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.rangeSlider.setVideoURL(videoURL: url!)
        self.rangeSlider.minSpace = 5.0
        self.rangeSlider.maxSpace = 30.0
        self.rangeSlider.setStartPosition(seconds: 0.0)
        self.rangeSlider.setEndPosition(seconds: 30.0)
        self.rangeSlider.updateProgressIndicator(seconds: 0.0)
        self.rangeSlider.updateThumbnails()
    }


    func didChangeValue(videoRangeSlider: ABVideoRangeSlider, startTime: Float64, endTime: Float64) {
        print(startTime)    // Prints the position of the Start indicator in seconds
        print(endTime)      // Prints the position of the End indicator in seconds
    }

    func indicatorDidChangePosition(videoRangeSlider: ABVideoRangeSlider, position: Float64) {
        print(position)      // Prints the position of the Progress indicator in seconds
    }
}
```

I've also downloaded the example project to see what's wrong, but I don't know why
what's the problem.

My project:

[image]

example project:

[image]

example code:

[image]

```swift
import UIKit
import ABVideoRangeSlider
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, ABVideoRangeSliderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var videoRangeSlider: ABVideoRangeSlider!
    @IBOutlet var playerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var lblStart: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblEnd: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblMinSpace: UILabel!

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType:"mp4")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: Any) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        videoRangeSlider.setVideoURL(videoURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        videoRangeSlider.delegate = self
        videoRangeSlider.minSpace = 60.0
        //        videoRangeSlider.maxSpace = 180.0

        lblMinSpace.text = "\(videoRangeSlider.minSpace)"

        // Set initial position of Start Indicator
        videoRangeSlider.setStartPosition(seconds: 50.0)

        // Set initial position of End Indicator
        videoRangeSlider.setEndPosition(seconds: 150.0)
    }

    // MARK: ABVideoRangeSlider Delegate - Returns time in seconds
    func didChangeValue(videoRangeSlider: ABVideoRangeSlider, startTime: Float64, endTime: Float64) {
        lblStart.text = "\(startTime)"
        lblEnd.text = "\(endTime)"
    }

    func indicatorDidChangePosition(videoRangeSlider: ABVideoRangeSlider, position: Float64) {
        print("position of indicator: \(position)")
    }
}
```